How to fetch ENS domain details
I want a functionality using which i can get the address by passing a domain name for multiple domains like .eth,.bnb,.arb,.polygon. I tried multiple servcies but most of them only supports .eth , i have also tried space id packages but they are just too slow with a rate limit. it would be really helpful if you can suggest/provide any package which gives the detail about an ENS domain name (.eth , .bnb , .arb , .polygon) and vice versa.
